# How the ancient iron Pillar of Delhi was created?

Tags: ancient-india

Afaik, even in the middle ages was it impossible to melt iron. Thus, alloys had to be also impossible. Next to that, the ancient Indians surely didn't knew nickel, which is alloyed into the today's rust-free steels.

Thus, how was it reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Iron Age in India began around [1200 BCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painted_Grey_Ware_culture). The Pillar of Delhi was created around [400 CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandragupta_II), 1600 years after Indians had first learned to melt iron. Alloys weren't impossible. In fact, Indians had learned to make steel (not just wrought iron) by 200 CE, and possibly as early as [300 BCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_metallurgy_in_the_Indian_subcontinent#Wootz_and_steel).